# Default Role Provider could not be found asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, role-manager

In my web config file I gave written this block of code

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/AltuaWebsite" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
    <add applicationName="/AltuaWebsite" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I am getting this error

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The connection name 'ApplicationServices' was
>   not found in the applications configuration or the connection string
>   is empty.

Anyone knows what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

The error is stating that there is no connection by the name of `ApplicationServices`.

You will need to add it to the `web.config`, as an example:

```
<connectionStrings> 
     <add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString="[connection info here]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```